# Instances conflicting on events

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to make a dropdown. It works fine except for when I click on one to expand and then click on the other, then when I make a selection on one of them both close. What is the work around this as well as well as what is the best practice/approach for this situations.

```js
var extend = function(){
  if(!arguments.length)
   return {};
  else if (arguments.length == 1)
   return arguments[0];
   
  var primary = arguments[0];
  for(var v = 1; v < arguments.length; ++v){
   for(prop in arguments[v]){
    primary[prop] = arguments[v][prop];
   } 
  }
  return primary;
 };
 
 var Dropdown = (function(){
  self = undefined;  
  Dropdown.instances = [];
  
  function Dropdown(element, options){
   self = this;
   this.settings = extend(this.defaults, options);
   console.log(this.settings);
   this.element = this.getElement(element);
   
   this.trigger = this.getElement(options.trigger);
   
   if(!this.element)
    throw new Error('No element found.');
    
   if(!this.trigger)
    throw new Error('No trigger found.');
    
   if(!this.settings.optionSelector)
    throw new Error('Option Selector Not Defined.');

   if(this.element.dropdown)
    throw new Error('Dropdown already exists.');
    
    
   this.element.dropdown = this;
   Dropdown.instances.push(this);
   
   
   
   this.attachTriggerListener = function(event, trigger, dropdown){
    trigger.addEventListener(event, function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     dropdown.classList.remove('hidden');
     dropdown.classList.add('visible');
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){  
     dropdown.classList.remove('visible');
     dropdown.classList.add('hidden');
     trigger.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
    }, false);
   };
   
   this.init();
  }
  Dropdown.prototype.defaults = {
   css: '',
   optionSelector: undefined,
   trigger: undefined,
   triggersOn: 'click',
   onShow: function(){},
   onClose: function(){},
  };
  Dropdown.prototype.init = function(){
   this.element.classList.add('g-dropdown');
   this.element.classList.add('hidden');
   
   
   this.attachTriggerListener(this.settings.triggersOn, this.trigger, this.element);  
  };  
  Dropdown.prototype.getElement = function(object){
   if(typeof object == 'object' &&
   object instanceof HTMLElement)
    return object;
   else if(typeof object == 'string')
    return document.querySelector(object);
  };   
  
  return Dropdown;
 }());


 var dropdown = new Dropdown('#select', {
  optionSelector: 'li',
  trigger: '#trigger'
 });
 
 
 var dropdown = new Dropdown('#select2', {
  optionSelector: 'li',
  trigger: '#trigger2'
 });
```

```css
.g-dropdown{ 
 max-height: 100px;
 max-width: 75px;
 
 overflow: scroll;
 
 -webkit-transition: visibility 0.50s, height 0.50s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0.50s, height 0.50s;
   transition: visibility 0.50s, height 0.50s;
}
.g-dropdown.visible{
 visibility: visible;
 height: 100px;
}
.g-dropdown.hidden{
 visibility: hidden;
 height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button id='trigger'>Click Me</button>
<ul id='select' style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
 <li>One-one</li>
 <li>Two-two</li>
 <li>Three-three</li>
 <li>Four-four</li>
 <li>Five-five</li>
</ul>



<br/><br/><br/>

<button id='trigger2'>Click Me</button>
<ul id='select2' style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
 <li>One-one</li>
 <li>Two-two</li>
 <li>Three-three</li>
 <li>Four-four</li>
 <li>Five-five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Throwing error at `if(!this.settings.optionSelector)
    throw new Error('Option Selector Not Defined.');`

Comment: thanks for replying, but I think you are missing the point here. I am trying to solve the instances issues.

Comment: Appear to be duplicate `dropdown` variable names at initialization . See post

Answer (score 1):

> So how would I have to modify it so it also closes the dropdown on
>   clicking outside the dropdown?

Try checking `e.target.parentElement.nodeName` ,  `this.element.nodeName` at `if` condition within `document.addEventListener` handler , adding , removing `class` of `dropdown` if parent element is `ul` , else adjusting `class` of clicked `li` parent element `ul`

```
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
        if (e.target.parentElement.nodeName !== this.element.nodeName) {
          dropdown.classList.remove('visible');
          dropdown.classList.add('hidden');
        } else {              
          e.target.parentElement.classList.remove('visible');
          e.target.parentElement.classList.add('hidden');
        }
        self.settings.onClose(e.target);
    }.bind(this), false);
```

```js
var extend = function(){
  if(!arguments.length)
   return {};
  else if (arguments.length == 1)
   return arguments[0];
   
  var primary = arguments[0];
  for(var v = 1; v < arguments.length; ++v){
   for(prop in arguments[v]){
    primary[prop] = arguments[v][prop];
   } 
  }
  return primary;
 };
 
 var Dropdown = (function(){
  self = undefined;  
  Dropdown.instances = [];
  
  function Dropdown(element, options){
   self = this;
   this.settings = extend(this.defaults, options);
   console.log(this.settings);
   this.element = this.getElement(element);
   
   this.trigger = this.getElement(options.trigger);
   
   if(!this.element)
    throw new Error('No element found.');
    
   if(!this.trigger)
    throw new Error('No trigger found.');
      /*
   if(!this.settings.optionSelector)
    throw new Error('Option Selector Not Defined.');
            */

   if(this.element.dropdown)
    throw new Error('Dropdown already exists.');
    
    
   this.element.dropdown = this;
   Dropdown.instances.push(this);
   
   
   
   this.attachTriggerListener = function(event, trigger, dropdown){
    trigger.addEventListener(event, function(e){                   
     e.stopPropagation();
     dropdown.classList.remove('hidden');
     dropdown.classList.add('visible');
    }, false);
              
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
                    if (e.target.parentElement.nodeName !== this.element.nodeName) {
       dropdown.classList.remove('visible');
       dropdown.classList.add('hidden');
     
                    } else {
                                               e.target.parentElement.classList.remove('visible');
       e.target.parentElement.classList.add('hidden');
                    }
self.settings.onClose(e.target);
    }.bind(this), false);

                
   };
   
   this.init();
  }
  Dropdown.prototype.defaults = {
   css: '',
   optionSelector: undefined,
   trigger: undefined,
   triggersOn: 'click',
   onShow: function(){},
   onClose: function(){},
  };
  Dropdown.prototype.init = function(){
   this.element.classList.add('g-dropdown');
   this.element.classList.add('hidden');
   
   
   this.attachTriggerListener(this.settings.triggersOn, this.trigger, this.element);  
  };  
  Dropdown.prototype.getElement = function(object){
   if(typeof object == 'object' &&
   object instanceof HTMLElement)
    return object;
   else if(typeof object == 'string')
    return document.querySelector(object);
  };   
  
  return Dropdown;
 }());


 var dropdown1 = new Dropdown('#select', {
  optionSe1lector: 'li',
  trigger: '#trigger'
 });
 
 
 var dropdown2 = new Dropdown('#select2', {
  optionSe2lector: 'li',
  trigger: '#trigger2'
 });
```

```css
.g-dropdown{ 
 max-height: 100px;
 max-width: 75px;
 
 overflow: scroll;
 
 -webkit-transition: visibility 0.50s, height 0.50s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 0.50s, height 0.50s;
   transition: visibility 0.50s, height 0.50s;
}
.g-dropdown.visible{
 visibility: visible;
 height: 100px;
}
.g-dropdown.hidden{
 visibility: hidden;
 height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button id='trigger'>Click Me</button>
<ul id='select' style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
 <li>One-one</li>
 <li>Two-two</li>
 <li>Three-three</li>
 <li>Four-four</li>
 <li>Five-five</li>
</ul>



<br/><br/><br/>

<button id='trigger2'>Click Me</button>
<ul id='select2' style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
 <li>One-one</li>
 <li>Two-two</li>
 <li>Three-three</li>
 <li>Four-four</li>
 <li>Five-five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes , tried. _"because that does not work."_ . See OP at _"then when I make a selection on one of them both close."_ Attempted to solve for that specific portion Question . Not certain what expected result is ? 1) Click on "Click Me" opens list, 2) click on list closes list ? Appear `click` on list item toggles list from visible to hidden ?

Comment: Ok, so I have edited, try expanding both and then make a selection on one of them. You will see that both get the same value.

Comment: @Gacci Each list item parent elements have same element name `li`, same  `.visible` , `.hidden` classes which apply `css` to both sets of elements at `click` event .

Comment: Could you show me how to make it work. I don't see why that would be a problem. Showing or hiding has to do with the listener. And as I mentioned, that is not really the issue, the real issue is that both get the same value

Comment: _"the real issue is that both get the same value "_ Not certain what "value" is ? can describe what "same value" is ? Is expected result for only clicked list to toggle ,  instead of both list   ?

Comment: I mentioned before. Expand one then expand the other. You will notice that both buttons get the same value. (try it on my original post. I have edited so you can see the problem)

Comment: So how would I have to modify it so it also closes the dropdown on clicking outside the dropdown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95004/discussion-between-guest271314-and-gacci).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `event.currentTarget` to know which element triggers the event and so find the element you need this target to show, that way your code will shorter and simpler

Try something like this:

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn-1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn-2');

function toggle(event) {
  var nextNode = event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
  nextNode.classList.toggle('disable');
  nextNode.classList.toggle('enable');
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
btn2.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
```

```css
.disable {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.enable {
  max-height: initial;
  overflow: initial
}
```

```html
<div class="first-container">
  <button id="btn-1">Click Me</button>
  <ul id="list-1" class="disable">
    <li>item-1</li>
    <li>item-2</li>
    <li>item-3</li>
    <li>item-4</li>
    <li>item-5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="second-container">
  <button id="btn-2">Click Me</button>
  <ul id="list-2" class="disable">
    <li>item-1</li>
    <li>item-2</li>
    <li>item-3</li>
    <li>item-4</li>
    <li>item-5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```